# Get All Pdf Files from My Computer Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I want to get all the PDF files from my MyComputer Folder. I have written the code which is getting all of my drives successfully but there is an exception occurring and none of file is accessible. Here is the exception message. Please help me for this.

> "Access to the path 'C:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-18' is denied."

My requirement is to get all the pdf files and their paths from My Computer folder.

Comment: If you iterate over all directories, there will of course be some you don't have access to. Simply catch that exception and move on.

Comment: also, it might or might not help to run your script/app as admin if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

if you are running your C# program from visual studio: close VS and run it as administrator

if you are running your C# program alone from created .exe file in bin

try to run that as an administrator account

I hope it'll be helpfull